# how to convert bayerrg8 format image to rgb image

Tags: scikit-image, pixelformat

I've got a camera that provides images in Bayer RG8 format.

I'm using skimage for processing images, but I could not find away to convert the Bayer RG8 format to standard RGB (to display on screen).

Is there any way to do this with skimage?

I did find a reference to opencv conversion, but I'm trying to avoid including opencv in my app (unless it is absolutely necessary).

Comment: Do you have sample data files to share? Do you have some preferred algorithm as there are many... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing

Comment: You should also clarify your sensor layout - it could be `'gbrg' | 'grbg' | 'bggr' | 'rggb'`

Answer (score 6):

As you have not provided any input data, I took the greyscale image from [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/demosaic.html) and made it into a raw Bayer8 file with GBRG ordering using **ImageMagick** as follows:

```
magick mandi.png -trim -depth 8 gray:bayer.bin
```

which gives me an 1013x672 pixel file of 680,736 bytes.

Then I read it like this and made it into an image that skimage can understand like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imsave

# Width and height of Bayer image, not original which is w/2 x h/2
w, h = 1013, 672
ow, oh = w//2, h//2

# Load in Bayer8 image, assumed raw 8-bit GBRG
bayer = np.fromfile('bayer.bin', dtype=np.uint8).reshape((h,w))

# Pick up raw uint8 samples
R  = bayer[1::2, 0::2]     # rows 1,3,5,7 columns 0,2,4,6
B  = bayer[0::2, 1::2]     # rows 0,2,4,6 columns 1,3,5,7
G0 = bayer[0::2, 0::2]     # rows 0,2,4,6 columns 0,2,4,6
G1 = bayer[1::2, 1::2]     # rows 1,3,5,7 columns 1,3,5,7

# Chop any left-over edges and average the 2 Green values
R = R[:oh,:ow]
B = B[:oh,:ow]
G = G0[:oh,:ow]//2 + G1[:oh,:ow]//2

# Formulate image by stacking R, G and B and save
out = np.dstack((R,G,B)) 
imsave('result.png',out)
```

And get this:

[image]

Copyright Mathworks, Inc.

Of course, there are more sophisticated methods of interpolating, but this is the most basic and you are welcome to take it and improve it!

---

Ok, I had some time and I tried to do a 2d-interpolation of the missing values in the Bayer array. I am not 100% confident of my answer, but I think it should be pretty close.

Basically, I copy the original Bayer array at full resolution, and overwrite all green and blue samples with `np.Nan` and call that Red. Then I do a 2d-interpolation to replace the Nans.

Same again for green and blue, that gives this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imsave
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

def interp2d(im):
    """Interpolate in 2d array, replacing NaNs with interpolated values"""
    x, y = np.indices(im.shape)
    im[np.isnan(im)] = griddata(
       (x[~np.isnan(im)], y[~np.isnan(im)]),
       im[~np.isnan(im)],
       (x[np.isnan(im)], y[np.isnan(im)]))
    im = np.nan_to_num(im)
    return np.clip((im),0,255)

# Width and height of Bayer image
w, h = 1013, 672

# Calculate output width and height as multiples of 4
ow = (w//4) * 4
oh = (h//4) * 4

# Load in Bayer8 image, assumed raw 8-bit GBRG, reshape and make sides multiple of 4
bayer = np.fromfile('bayer.bin', dtype=np.uint8).reshape((h,w)).astype(np.float)[:oh, :ow]

# In following code you'll see "cell" which is the basic repeating 2x2 cell of a Bayer matrix
#
# cell = G B
#        R G
#

# Set everything not Red in bayer array to Nan, then replace Nans with interpolation
cell = np.array([[np.NaN, np.NaN],
                 [1.0   , np.NaN]])
R = bayer*np.tile(cell,(oh//2,ow//2))
R = interp2d(R).astype(np.uint8)

# Set everything not Green in bayer array to Nan, then replace Nans with interpolation
cell = np.array([[1.0   , np.NaN],
                 [np.NaN, 1.0   ]])
G = bayer*np.tile(cell,(oh//2,ow//2))
G = interp2d(G).astype(np.uint8)

# Set everything not Blue in bayer array to Nan, then replace Nans with interpolation
cell = np.array([[np.NaN, 1.0   ],
                 [np.NaN, np.NaN]])
B = bayer*np.tile(cell,(oh//2,ow//2))
B = interp2d(B).astype(np.uint8)

# Form image by stacking R, G and B and save
imsave('result.png',np.dstack((R,G,B)))
```

---

**Keywords**: Python, bayer, bayer8, debayer, de-bayer, de-mosaic, de-mosaicking, image, raw, CFA, skimage, scikit-image, image processing.

Comment: Hi Mark.  I think I like the 2nd method feels better.  I was actually thinking about get the red pixels and then calling a `resize` function to to double the dimensions (assuming that some kind of interpolation happens).  Do the same for blue pixels.  I'm not sure how to do something similar with the green pixels (maybe they are ok just as is?).  The finally stack the RGB data.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: That is exactly what my first approach does, except I didn't add a `resize()` at the end to double its height and width. As regards having two samples in the Green channel at each pixel location, I simply average them and then treat them just the same as Red and Blue.

Comment: Yeah, understood that.  I was trying to be cute by keeping the original green bits, and filling in the missing green bits.  It worked but there was a # pattern when I zoomed in.  The first method actually yielded better results for me than my method.  I didn't try your method with the hand-crafted interpolation.