# Color reproduction using linear matrix coefficients

Tags: image-processing

I have some raw image data to feed into a program that performs debyaering/demosaicing to get a color image.

There is a 3x3 matrix given to me for use in color reproduction, which are the linear matrix coefficients for this type of image sensor.

I'm trying to get my head around some beginner concepts in image processing and I am not sure when or how to apply the 3x3 matrix to achieve some type of color reproduction or correction.  And, is this related to convolution kernels somehow, e.g. multiply and sum the numbers in the matrix with the pixel values to create an effect, in this case color reproduction/color correction?

Thank you, I hope to be able to rephrase this question if I can for clarity.

I think what would happen is that the demosaic/debayer part is done first, then the image is in "real" color space, then the matrix with its 3x3 of real numbers is used *somehow* for color reproduction or correction.

Comment: This may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60848253/2836621 and this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693798/2836621